# How to close boostrap 5 submenu in vertical navigation clicking on a another link without submenu

Tags: navigation, bootstrap-5

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="generator" content="">
    <title>Navigation Test</title>

   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

  <style type="text/css">
    .sidebar li .submenu{
     list-style: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     padding-left: 1rem;
     padding-right: 1rem;
    }
  </style>
  
<body>
<nav class="sidebar card py-2 mb-4">
    <ul class="nav flex-column" id="accordion">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sub_menu_1" href="#">Link 2<i class="bi small bi-caret-down-fill"></i> </a>
            <ul id="sub_menu_1" class="submenu collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sub_menu_2" href="#">Link 3<i class="bi small bi-caret-down-fill"></i> </a>
            <ul id="sub_menu_2" class="submenu collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 5</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>    

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried an example of a vertical navigation containing single links and also 2 links opening a submenu each. If I click on Link 2, the submenu opens. Next click on the other link with submenu (link 3) opens the corresponding submenu. The submenu under link 2 is atomatically closed. That's perfect.

My problem is now, how to close an open submenu if I click on a single menu link (links 1,4,5).

Expected behaviour would be that any open submenu will close and the target of the link is called in case clicking on a link without a submenu.

Here's the code:

Answer (score 0):

It seems that empty links won't auto-close submenus.

So, you could add empty element below each top level link, with parent just like submenus, so auto-hiding would work:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#link1">Link 1</a>
<!-- empty, just to trigger auto-close -->
<span id="link1" data-bs-parent="#accordion"></span>
```

demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="generator" content="">
  <title>Navigation Test</title>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

  <style type="text/css">
    .sidebar li .submenu {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      padding-left: 1rem;
      padding-right: 1rem;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <nav class="sidebar card py-2 mb-4">
      <ul class="nav flex-column" id="accordion">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#link1">Link 1</a>
          <span id="link1" data-bs-parent="#accordion"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sub_menu_1" href="#">Link 2<i class="bi small bi-caret-down-fill"></i> </a>
          <ul id="sub_menu_1" class="submenu collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sub_menu_2" href="#">Link 3<i class="bi small bi-caret-down-fill"></i> </a>
          <ul id="sub_menu_2" class="submenu collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#link4">Link 4</a>
          <span id="link4" data-bs-parent="#accordion"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#link5">Link 5</a>
          <span id="link5" data-bs-parent="#accordion"></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

---

Or you could do it with JavaScript: add click listener on top level links and close opened menu with JavaScript:

*note: you need to use Bootstrap 5.3 for this*

demo:

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item > .nav-link');

function close(e) {

  const menu = document.querySelector('.submenu.collapse.show');

  if (menu) {
    bootstrap.Collapse.getOrCreateInstance(menu).hide();
  }
}

links.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', close));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="generator" content="">
  <title>Navigation Test</title>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

  <style type="text/css">
    .sidebar li .submenu {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      padding-left: 1rem;
      padding-right: 1rem;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <nav class="sidebar card py-2 mb-4">
      <ul class="nav flex-column" id="accordion">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sub_menu_1" href="#">Link 2<i class="bi small bi-caret-down-fill"></i> </a>
          <ul id="sub_menu_1" class="submenu collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sub_menu_2" href="#">Link 3<i class="bi small bi-caret-down-fill"></i> </a>
          <ul id="sub_menu_2" class="submenu collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </body>

</html>
```